# Two measures with a common full measure set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be an arbitrary space, and let $\mu, \nu$ be two probability measures on $X$. Suppose there is a common set $A$ on which $\mu(A) = \nu(A) = 1$.

Now suppose there are $B, C$ such that $\mu(B) = \nu(C) = 1$. Can anything be said of $\mu(C)$ and $\nu(B)$, or $\mu(B \cap C)$ and $\nu(B \cap C)$?

My initial intuition was that the answer should be yes since $B \cap A$ and $C \cap A$ both have full $\mu$ and full $\nu$ measure respectively, and so there should be "enough" overlap for $B \cap C$ to have at least positive measure. But I can't seem to prove this - so I'm interested in whether anything can be said of these quantities (either alone or possibly together, e.g. is it possible for $\mu(C) = \nu(B) = 0$) and whether there is any clever counterexample for which $\mu(C)$ and $\nu(B)$ can be any arbitrary number in $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that such a set $A$ always exists, namely $X$ itself. Hence, we can't really say anything non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - would I be able to say anything if $A \subsetneq X$? I'm guessing no since $A$ can "almost" be $X$?

Comment: Your intuition is correct!